# Why can't Vulcans lie given that it is logical to tell a white lie?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, star-trek-into-darkness

Adult humans know it is logical to tell white lies in some situations. Every one of us does that. See what happened in the movie "Star Trek Into Darkness" when Spock refused to lie and wrote truthfully in his report how Kirk broke the Prime Directive. Kirk did it to save Spock's life. For saving his friend's life, Kirk lost his ship and job as Captain of the Enterprise because his Vulcan friend cannot lie.

https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/star_trek_into_darkness/quotes/

> Kirk: Where I come from, if someone saves your life, you don't stab
> him in the back.
>
> Spock: Vulcans can not lie.

Why can't Vulcans lie when it is a logical thing to do sometimes? Why can't Vulcans, with all their powers of logic, cannot see the logic?

Comment: Spock is half-human. Therefore he may have an idealised view of the Vulcan race, similar how ex-pats often do about their own countries (or indeed, Worf does in ST:TNG / DS9)

Comment: They can. They do, all the time. This is just shoddy writing, typical of the new movie franchise. It's not as bad as Discovery, though, which has claimed that Vulcans are literally incapable of experiencing or understanding emotions — remarkable, since their entire backstory is predicated on the notion that they experience them more than anyone, which is _why_ they have to suppress them! Meh. Rant over... ;)

Comment: Vulcans have been stated as "unable to lie" on multiple occasions before, so that is not "shoddy writing typical of the new movie franchise" @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @MatthewBarclay This has been shown to be false on several occasions. Simply click through to the duplicate for some examples.